# How can I use custom cursor C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mouse-cursor

well i wanna ask you first how can I add a custom cursor to my c# application where i have the (.cur) file?

second i want to add two custom cursors which are open hand and closed hand (like the ones used in the adobe acrobat reader or the ones used in windows photo viewr) because i have a drag n drop functionality.

So please where can i find the .cur files to those curosrs, i have searched the whole web but i got nothing. i have found one on a forum said that i can find the open hand cursor in one of the resources inside an assembly in the Microsoft expression blend. I have the .Net reflector and i extracted the .cur file from that assembly .. but i didn't find a closed hand cursor!!!

so please can you help me in that

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight does not support true custom cursors.  The best you can do is move an image about the display as the mouse moves.