# Change mouse cursor in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mouse

I have to change the default cursor in Silverlight to  custom .cur file that I have with me int the resources. I will have to do the same in App.xaml.cs.

Any pointers to this please?

Comment: Check out the similar post below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273325/how-can-i-use-custom-cursor-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight does not support custom mouse cursors, inherently. As such, you will have to look into creating your own and loading the .cur file as the source of the visual part of the cursor. A Google search or two should give you some resources and forums on similar approaches to the issue. [Here](http://www.gigyonline.com/code/source/silverlight/CustomMouseCursor.html) is one example project that may help you with your approach.

Comment: @Samueal Slade: Thanks for the link. I understand that we can use a user control to get a custom cursor according to our requirement. Can we get this as a default behaviour through App.xaml.cs?